# php Get unicode codepoint for UTF-8 glyph

Tags: php, unicode

I need to get the hex unicode codepoint for glyphs.

What I am doing that works *most* of the time is:

```
$hex = dechex(unpack('V', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4LE', $glyph)[1]);
```

Where ut fails:

ȳ
ȳ́
ȳ̂
ȳ̀
ȳ͂

All of those return 233 but 233 is only correct in the first instance. The others are different glyphs that render differently.

It seems to fail when there is more than one diacritic mark involved, but sometimes it gets it right.

Why is it failing that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the way the text is composed depends on the software that composed it, and unless that software provides guarantees or you make it a point to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) the input you really can't make assumptions.

Even in the simplest (first) example, the input could be legitimately composed of the single glyph LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH MACRON' (U+0233) or the two code point combination LATIN SMALL LETTER Y (U+0079) and COMBINING MACRON (U+0304). You would get different results in each case, even though the input would be visually and semantically identical (the only difference being byte-wise, which is an implementation detail).

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now, means I have to rewrite some code but I was doing it wrong so...